# insert dictionaries as rows in sqlite table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, dictionary

I have dictionaries like this:

```
{'id': 8, 'name': 'xyzzy', 'done': False}
```

the table is already created with the correct column names (keys of the dictionary). How can I insert the values in the respective columns? I want to create a new row for each dictionary.

Note that for 'done' the type defined is originally Integer since sqlite does not offer bool type.

```
cur = connection().cursor()
```

```
query = "insert .... tablename"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, database cursors accept two parameters:

1. an SQL statement as a string: the statement may contain placeholders instead of some values to handle cases where the values are not known until runtime.
2. a *collection* of *values* to be inserted into the SQL statement.  These values replace the placeholders in the SQL statement when it is executed.

Placeholders may be positional or named:

```py
# Positional placeholders: the order of values should match the order of 
# placeholders in the statement.  Values should be contained with
# a tuple or list, even if there is only one.
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = ? AND age = ?""", ('Alice', 42))

# Named placeholders: values and placeholders are matched by name, order 
# is irrelevant.  Values must be contained within a mapping (dict) of
# placeholders to values.
cur.execute(
    """SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = :name AND age = :age""", 
    {'age': 42, 'name': 'Alice'}
)
```

You can dictionary to cursor execute and it will do the right thing as long as the values placeholders in the SQL statement used the `:named` format (that is, the dict key prefixed by a colon ":").

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect()
cur = conn.cursor()
stmt = """INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, done) VALUES (:id, :name, :done)"""
cur.execute(stmt, {'id': 8, 'name': 'xyzzy', 'done': False})
# Call commit() on the connection to "save" the data.
conn.commit()
```

This method ensures that values are correctly quoted before being inserted into the database and protects against SQL injection attacks.

See also the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: can you explain this syntax/format a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.format()` method to insert into a query string however this is much more straightforward.

`dic = {'id': 8, 'name': 'xyzzy', 'done': False}`

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (:id,:name,:done)",{"id" : dic["id"],"name" : dic["name"],"done" : dic["done"]})`

Comment: can you explain this syntax/format a bit?

Comment: @x89 format method acts as a placeholder in the string, for your particular question I would've used the method this way in the string `"INSERT INTO tablename (id, name, done) VALUES ({ },{ },{ })".format(dic["id"], dic["name"], dic["done"])`. `{ }` acts as a placeholder and takes the value **based on order** from format's arguments.